# Is there a way to dynamically reference a closed Excel sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, reference, cell

I manually update file references in a sheet using the Find and Replace function. There must be a better way.

I am aware that dynamic sheet references can be achieved with the INDIRECT function. I tried this, but it requires the target file to be open.

```
HLOOKUP($B$1,INDIRECT("'[FY23 Budget - Flat file.xlsx]"&$D8&"'!$FR$135:$HQ$245"),25,FALSE)
```

Solutions I found claim that this is not possible with standard formulas.

Is there a way with VBA?

The file reference is:

```
S:\Finance\WR & Stats 2022-2023\Daily Sales Report\FY23\WK26\[Daily Sales Report - Sunday.xlsx]Daily Sales'!
```

Where I am trying to change the WK26 to WK27 or whichever.

Comment: You say you use Find and Replace to do it manually. You can write vba code to do that process.  Start by recording a macro while you do it, then tidy that code up.

Comment: Just to add, a LookUp function with 'normal' cell references can return a value from closed files, but as you say can't if the reference is an INDIRECT function. The VBA to Find & Replace your updated references in formulas might be quite simple, try what @chrisnelson suggested but without Indirect

Answer (score 0):

You can't use standard formulas, but VBA can connect to a closed workbook that is open in memory.
Use something like the following.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Dim loadWorkbookFileName As String
   loadWorkbookFileName = &lt;path to file&gt;

   Dim loadWorkbook As Workbook
   Set loadWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=loadWorkbookFileName, ReadOnly:=True, _
                     Format:=xlExcel7)

   Dim worksheet As Excel.Worksheet
   Set worksheet = loadWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

   Dim lastRow As Integer
   lastRow = worksheet.Range("A" &amp; worksheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

   For iRow = 1 To lastRow    
       ' Do something with worksheet cells here
   Next iRow

   loadWorkbook.Close
   Set loadWorkbook = Nothing

End Sub
```

And put the above code in a module in the workbook (Same process as adding a worksheet)